# Finding a confidence interval given sample size, mean, and standard error

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am not the best with Statistics, and I was wondering if it is possible (and how, if it is) to find a 93% Confidence Interval given Sample Size (27), Mean (6.73), and Standard Error (1.732). Thank you!

Comment: Step 1: Put the keywords into Google. Step 2: [read the step-by-step guide with example](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-calculate-a-confidence-interval-for-a-popul.html). Step 3: do it for your own data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know (or assume) the distribution of the data in order to compute a confidence interval just using sample size, mean, and standard error. For example, you could assume a Gaussian distribution. If you have the full set of actual samples, and don't want to assume a distribution, then you can simply compute the 0.035 and 0.965 empirical quantiles in the sample and use that as your 93% confidence interval.